# Not able to remove index.php in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

`$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/packagekartlive/';`

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

.htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

rewrite mode on.

FOR YOUR KIND INFORMATION

The same version of the application works fine on the live server and do no work in the local machine. I have tried almost all solutions on this site.

I have also tried the solution given in documentation of CodeIgniter as well.

Please suggest some quick fix.

Comment: .htaccess file is parallel to application folder in the project folder

Comment: code image for which file

Comment: *"not duplicate"* - Huh? that needs to be removed from the title. If you won't, then I will and to not be added back in. Otherwise, the post will be flagged.

Comment: _“I have also tried the solution given in documentation of CodeIgniter as well.”_ - which one? Be specific - _link_ to the exact place you are referring to, instead of most vaguely mentioning that you did something like it was suggested someplace somewhere ... _“works fine on the live server and do no work in the local machine”_ - again, be specific: What does “not working” mean, _exactly_? Please go read [ask].

Comment: Restart your Apache maybe? (Hoping you use Apache ...)

Comment: Finding a good (or even a half-decent) duplicate for something is really hard. That is why there are mechanisms to support this through experienced users. Please consider them helpful and not an attack on a question. Verifying that there is no duplicate in the many SO Q/As would be superhuman, or lets at least say "hard to believe". So the best you can do in order to demonstrate the "non-duplicate" is to refer to the similar-but-not-duplicates you have found and explain why this is not a duplicate of any of them. That indeed would be an upvotable demonstration of own research effort.

Comment: @Yunnosch thanks for the advice as explained by Jay Blanchard I totally agree with this concept. From the next time, I will try to ask better and more well-defined question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in .htacccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Or

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: can share my screen on anydesk or any other software if you are willing

Comment: which server have you

Comment: wamp server on local machine and hostgator hosting as production server

Comment: You can check using from 

https://support.hostgator.com/articles/apache-mod_rewrite-and-examples

i think you have shared server.

and check the code

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=302]
# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301,L]


or generate ticket to enable the RewriteEngine to hostgator

Answer (score -1):

If you're testing on a local server and are running WAMP, click on the Green WAMP icon in the taskbar. Scroll over Apache and then scroll over Apache Modules. Make sure that rewrite_module has a green checkmark next to it.

Comment: done already. not able to find the solution, so I have started development on remote server via ftp